# Recovering an increasing function from its partial derivatives at a maximum

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I have only the first partial derivatives of a multivariable function, and I am trying to recover the original function at a particular maximum. I have very little knowledge of PDEs, so sorry if the question is pretty basic.

In the one variable case, for some $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ that reaches a unique maximum at $f(x\text{*})$, we can write $$f(x\text{*}) = f(0) + \int_0^{x\text{*}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx$$

In the two variable case, for some $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that reaches a unique maximum at $f(x\text{*},y\text{*})$, is there a way to write $f(x\text{*},y\text{*})$ in the form as above? What about in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

For the sake of argument, let $f$ be increasing in $(x,y)$ and component-wise as well until $(x\text{*},y\text{*})$.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Corollary), and has nothing to do with the fact that $f$ has a unique maximum.

For higher dimensions, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariable_calculus#Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus_in_multiple_dimensions). Though I've only glossed over it, [this article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.511.6638) also seems to have a well-written exposition to Green's theorem.

Comment: Ah of course! Thank you for the reference.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, feel free to upvote/accept. Before you accept, you may want to wait for possibly more thorough answers. Also, welcome to Math.SE.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I am going to re-read it and try to figure out my problem. I will accept if this gives me what I need. Thanks so much again.

Comment: Actually I am unsure of whether this is directly related to Green's Theorem. I am dealing with a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, not a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: One of the links points to the gradient theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem), which deals with $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The idea is just to parameterize some curve by $t$ and apply the ordinary fundamental theorem of calc.

Comment: Ah okay. I just spent an hour brushing up on manifolds and generalized stokes. I think I got it now. Thanks so much again for your help.